# Convert array of objects into array of primitives (extracted from object properties)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Consider the following code:

```
var input = [{x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 4, y: 3}, {x: 9, y: 2}];

var output = convert(input);

console.log(output); // = [1, 6, 4, 3, 9, 2]
```

What is the shortest, most concise `convert` function I can write that will give me the `output` shown?

So far I've come up with the following:

```
function convert(input) {
  var output = [];
  input.forEach(function(obj) {
    output.push(obj.x, obj.y);
  });
  return output;
}
```

But surely there's a nice one-liner way of doing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code review.

Comment: @JamesHill [Vote to close because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, not because it belongs somewhere else](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286591/1310566). Voting to close because it belongs somewhere else can cause situations where the question is closed on two places. This question is not a very good fit for Code Review, although I think it would be on-topic (barely), I don't consider this question off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. OP is asking for help writing a function, also demonstrated his approach.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, just because there is an upvoted answer on Meta, doesn't mean I need to agree with it :-). Off Topic by design leads you to migrate to another site (Code Review isn't there because it was abused). In any case, that is the beauty of the voting system...if everyone agreed, no voting would be necessary.

Comment: @JamesHill [There are other answers as well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287401/1310566). The whole close-reason "off-topic because it belongs at ..." is nonsense. The on-topicness on other sites does not affect the on-topicness of Stack Overflow. I have also noticed that you are not registered on Code Review, I would recommend that you read some of our good questions and answers. This question attracts SO-style answers like "here's what I would do <codedump>", such answers are frowned upon on Code Review.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, golly, could you put together a checklist of all the meta questions and FAQ's I should read so that I can use the site acceptably? Is there anything I can read about reducing comment noise just because you don't agree with someone?

Comment: @JamesHill Let's make a deal, shall we? You stop voting close for bad reasons, I'll stop commenting about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method it will save you two lines of code:

```js
function convert(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev.concat(curr.x, curr.y);
    }, []);
}

var input = [{x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 4, y: 3}, {x: 9, y: 2}];

document.write(JSON.stringify( convert(input) ));
```